# Button click event not responding c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, onclick, event-handling

The problem we are having is accessing the click event for a button which is created in the click event of another button i.e. clicking the first button generates a new panel and controls, and we now want the button on this newly created panel to perform an action.

The controls have been declared at the top of the class as follows:

```
    Panel createElementPage = null;
    TextBox elementDescription = null;
    TextBox elementName = null;
    Button continueButton = null;
    AuditSystem audit;
```

Here is an excerpt of the method that generates the new panel, the part that defines the continueButton is written as follows:

```
    public void CE_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        createElementPage.Controls.Add(elementDescription);

        continueButton = new Button();
        continueButton.Text = "Continue";
        continueButton.Location = new Point(700, 500);
        continueButton.Size = new Size(100, 50);
        createElementPage.Controls.Add(continueButton);
    }
```

We want to access the continueButton's click event handler but the method we have written does not seem to be working. This is what we have so far:

```
       private void continueButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

        Console.WriteLine(" something");
        }
```

Clicking the button yields no results, and we have tried a few solutions such as implementing a seperate eventHandler method. Does anybody have a fix for this?

Comment: You need to subscribe to the click event `continueButton.Click += continueButton_Click;`

Comment: Discussed in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events

Answer (score 4):

You have to actually subscribe to the event:

```
continueButton.Click += continueButton_Click;
```

Events need to be told what they should handle. Without that, they won't "listen" to anything.

Friendly note: be careful when adding handlers "on demand" like this (i.e. outside of the designer). It doesn't really apply here (you have a new button each time), but it's fairly easy to accidentally subscribe to a control's event multiple times, and your handler will fire multiple times as a result. It's just nice to be aware of :)